# Sum of 2-d Random Array

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, parameters, variable-assignment

I am writing a program that creates a 2-d array, fills it with random numbers and then performs certain operations.

My `SumArray()` method is supposed to have a 2-dimensional array for the parameter list and will add all the numbers in the array and return the sum.  I know the way i have it now is wrong and I am stumped on how to do this.  Are my other methods in the program coded correctly so far or are they wrong and not allowing me to performm the tasks of the program?

Any help with the `SumArray()` method or any problems I have in other parts of the code is appreciated!! Thank you!

When I run my program I get an error that says Index was outside the bounds of the Array!

Here is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
        string[,] randomNumArray = new string[3, 5];

        FillArray(randomNumArray);
        PrintArray(randomNumArray);
        SumRows(randomNumArray);
        SumCols(randomNumArray);
        SumArray(randomNumArray);

    }

    public static void FillArray(int[,] randomNumbersArray)
    {
        Random num = new Random();
        for (int r = 0; r < randomNumbersArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < randomNumbersArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                randomNumbersArray[r, c] = num.Next(15, 97);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void PrintArray(int[,] randomPrintArray)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < randomPrintArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < randomPrintArray.GetLength(1); r++)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}", randomPrintArray[r, c]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static void SumRows(int[,] sumOfRowsArray)
    {
        int rowSum;
        for (int r = 0; r < sumOfRowsArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            rowSum = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < sumOfRowsArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                rowSum += sumOfRowsArray[r, c];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SumCols(int[,] sumOfColsArray)
    {
        int colsSum;
        for (int r = 0; r < sumOfColsArray.GetLength(1); r++)
        {
            colsSum = 0;

            for (int c = 0; c < sumOfColsArray.GetLength(0); c++)
            {
                colsSum += sumOfColsArray[r, c];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void SumArray(int[,] sumOfAllArray)
    {
        int sumOfAll 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            sumOfAll += sumOfAll;
            for (int c = 0; c < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                sumOfAll += sumOfAllArray[r, c];
            }
        }
        Console.Write(sumOfAll);
    }
```

Comment: SumRows() is the sum of the rows SumCols() is supposed to find the sum of the columns  and FillArray() is supposed to fill the array with random numbers

Comment: Is there any reason why you think those parts might be broken?  I'd try filling the rows/columns with something so that I knew what the sum should be and verify it (at least in easy cases).  For example, if I fill in all 1's I should know what to expect the sum to be.

Comment: My SumArray method has an error in it.  The sumOfAll += sumOfAll is bringing up an error therefore I can't run it to check anything.  I am confused on how to perform the sum of the Arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need that

```
sumOfAll += sumOfAll;
```

in `SumArray` method.
If I understand your code correctly, in the inner loop you count the column sum, then add it to itself in the next iteration? For example after inner loop you have first columns sum of 10. You add that 10 to itself and, before iterating over second column, you have total sum of 20.

The correct code:

```
public static void SumArray(int[,] sumOfAllArray)
{
    int sumOfAll;
    for (int r = 0; r < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(0); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < sumOfAllArray.GetLength(1); c++)
        {
            sumOfAll += sumOfAllArray[r, c];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for some reason when I delete the sumOfAll += sumOfAll it give me an error for the sumOfAll +=sumOfAllArray[r,c]   that say "use of unassigned local variable sumOfAll"

Comment: Hmm, you may not be initialising the variable. Try to change "int sumOfAll;" to "int sumOfAll = 0;" in the beginning of the method.

Comment: alrite I initialized it to zero but when I try to run the code now it says index was outside bounds of array.  I added these methods right below the declaration and creation of the array                         `FillArray(randomNumArray);`
`PrintArray(randomNumArray);`
`SumRows(randomNumArray);`
 `SumCols(randomNumArray);`
 `SumArray(randomNumArray);`                                                                                            In that order                                                                                                           I will edit the code above to Show

Comment: I also added a Console.Write(sumOfAll) statement in the SumArray Method to output the sum to check it.

Comment: Out of bounds in this method? This is c#? Well, the first thing I would do is to look if GetLength(0) and GetLength(1) aren't mixed up. Don't know why, but I have a feeling that GetLength(0) returns number of columns, andGetLength(1) returns number of rows. Give it a try: change 0 to 1 and vice versa:)

Comment: I have been taught that (0) returns the number of rows and (1) returs the number of columns.   Perhaps this is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this programming language. You are probably right about (0) and (1). In method "PrintArray" there is a mistake in line "for (int c = 0; c < randomPrintArray.GetLength(1); r++)". It should be "c++":)

Comment: error says it occurs at the `randomPrintArray()` Method

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it running atleast. there is still much more work to do so I will post more questions later!! THANK YOU!